# How to read files with strings and integers using fgets

Tags: c, fgets

I have noticed that `fscanf` is not working with determined C compilers (Intel, Cray), so I want to use `fgets` to read a simple input file that contains strings and integers

```
$cat input.txt
st 10 167 POP 456 244 NONE ENERGY
```

I could do something like this

```
int main()
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buf[1000];

    ptr_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (!ptr_file)
        return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        fgets(buf, 1000, ptr_file);
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;
}
```

to read the file and then create a `switch case` to either store the value of `buf` in an `integer` or a `string`. This is obviously not very efficient and I was wondering if anyone has a better idea.

Comment: The `fgets` will get your input into an array of characters.  You will still need to extract the data out of the character array.  In C, you can use `sscanf` after `fgets`.

Comment: Do you have a structure `struct` to hold the related values?  Or do you use a set of parallel arrays?  You need to know what you're going to replace the `printf()` with — how you are going to interpret and store what looks like 8 fields in the input for further processing.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `sscanf` seems to work OK, but `fscanf` fails...

Comment: "noticed that fscanf is not working" lacks description. What was the evidence of failure? what was expected?

Comment: My question is, Where are planning to store all this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using sscanf, essentially something like this

```
     // st 10 167 POP 456 244 NONE ENERGY
     sscanf(buf, "%s %d %d %s %d %d %s %s", var1, &var2....);
```

Comment: @_Aniruddh Dikhit Do you know why `sscanf` works and `fscanf` doesn't?

Comment: Much better to check the return value of `sscanf()` and use widths for `"%s"` like `"%9s"`.